# When do I need *-device-width?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm creating responsive web app for desktop and mobile devices. My problem is I don't know when I need to use `*-device-width`. Pls explain usecases for `*-device-width`. Why should I use it instead of `*-width`?

Comment: Pls lrn hw 2 wrt proper English ... it makes dealing with you much easier for others.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716066/difference-between-width-and-device-width-in-css-media-queries

Comment: Additional explanation in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305409/why-use-device-width

Answer (score 1):

You use it with a meta tag, which you will add to your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: What does this have to do with media queries?

Comment: The [viewport media tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag/) is not a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries/).

Answer (score 0):

From [Difference between width and device-width in CSS media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5716208?difference-between-width-and-device-width-in-css-media-queries):

> `device-width` is the...
>
> > width of the output device (meaning the entire screen or page, rather than just the rendering area, such as the document window).
>
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#device-width).
>
> The `width`...
>
> > describes the width of the rendering surface of the output device (such as the width of the document window, or the width of the page
> >     box on a printer)
>
> [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries#width).

Comment: Thanks but you haven't answer my question. Why should I use *-device-width instead of *-width?

Comment: There is a good explanation of this about halfway down this [page](http://www.elated.com/articles/responsive-web-design-demystified/)

Comment: Copy-pasting others' answers is plagiarism. Don't forget to give credits to the original author, eg by adding a link to the original post.

Comment: Sorry, I posted the original link in the comments above. I was just trying to make it so that they didn't have to hunt, didn't occur to me to repost the link. my bad.